# WPF/MVVM объединить модели во ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Буду излагать суть проблемы максимально кратко. Имеется 2 модели:

```
//Model1
class ClassModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ClassModel()
    {
        Fields = new ObservableCollection<FieldModel>();
        Methods = new ObservableCollection<MethodModel>();
        Properties = new ObservableCollection<PropertyModel>();
        Events = new ObservableCollection<EventModel>();
        uControl = new ClassUC
        {
            DataContext = this
        };
    }

    private UserControl uControl;
    public UserControl UControl
    {
        get
        {
            return uControl;
        }
    }

    private string className="test";
    public string ClassName
    {
        get
        {
            return className;
        }
        set
        {
            className = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ClassName");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<FieldModel> Fields { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MethodModel> Methods { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<PropertyModel> Properties { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<EventModel> Events { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

//Model2
class InterfaceModel
{
    public InterfaceModel()
    {
        Methods = new ObservableCollection<MethodModel>();
        Properties = new ObservableCollection<PropertyModel>();
        Events = new ObservableCollection<EventModel>();
        uControl = new InterfaceUC()
        {
            DataContext = this
        };
    }

    private UserControl uControl;
    public UserControl UControl
    {
        get
        {
            return uControl;
        }
    }

    private string className = "test";
    public string ClassName
    {
        get
        {
            return className;
        }
        set
        {
            className = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ClassName");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<FieldModel> Fields { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MethodModel> Methods { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<PropertyModel> Properties { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<EventModel> Events { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Как возможно их держать в одном списке, чтобы потом через ItemsControl выводить этот самый список, потому что эти классы похожи за исключением того, что InterfaceModel не содержит коллекции для типа FieldModel?

Comment: Кхм, какие-то странные у вас модели с UserControl и DataContext. И как это понимать: "...объединить модели во ViewModel"? Модели - это классы описывающие бизнес сущности, у которых понятные свойства: имя, дата, вес, возраст и т.п, а не как у вас Fields, Methods, Events... ViewModel должна иметь свойства типов классов модели. Например, есть класс Студент - это модель, есть класс MainViewModel и у нее есть свойства: `public ObservableCollection<Student> Students { get; set; }` и `public Student CurrentStudent { get; set; }`

Answer (score 2):

Что если создать базовый класс модели и унаследовать ваши модели от него?

В базовом классе будут реализованы все публичные свойства, а в конструкторе конкретного класса создавать коллекции для нужных типов.

```
public class BaseModel : INotifyPropertyChanged { /*общие свойства*/ } 
public class ConcreteModel1 : BaseModel { /*какой-то код*/ }
public class ConcreteModel2 : BaseModel { /*какой-то код*/ }

//--------------------------------------

var lists = new ObservableCollection<BaseModel>();
lists.add(new ConcreteModel1());
lists.add(new ConcreteModel2());
```